# How to run/build Apex code in the Welkin IDE.?

Tags: salesforce, apex, force.com

Salesforce Apex,
[The Welkin Suite IDE](https://welkinsuite.com/)

I'm trying this tool for salesforce development. but I can not understand how can I build/Run apex code locally. I've checked their website but didn't find any useful info.

is it possible? if yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce is a cloud-based platform. You cannot run Apex locally using any tool, period. You must deploy your Apex into a Salesforce environment in order to run it. You can sign up for a free [Developer Edition](https://developer.salesforce.com/) Salesforce org if you do not have access to one.